# React: Opening a PDF from 'blob' called to state. Using 'jsPDF'. Returns: Failed to load PDF document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I am trying to open pdf `onClick` after calling a `axios.get()`. To get data from mysql database.

The code for the button to open pdf is

```
class DownloadPdf extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.pdfGenerator = this.pdfGenerator.bind(this)
    }
    pdfGenerator(blob){
        console.log(blob)
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        var blobPDF = new Blob([doc.output[blob.data]], { type: 'application/pdf'})
        var BlobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF)
        window.open(BlobURL)

    }
render() {
    return (
        <td>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.pdfGenerator(this.props.blob)}}>
            Download PDF
        </button>
        </td>
    )
}
```

The input prop is `properties[obj].pdf_blob`

The blob object is:
`{type: "Buffer", data: Array(94869)}`

In parent I have used

```
.then(res => { this.setState({
    properties: res.data.data,
    isLoaded: true,
                })
            })
```

after my axios request to get data from database.